# Artifact deleted before finishing Download Pipeline Artifact task

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I created a pipeline to download the latest artifact from another pipeline and them list the archive. Here is my YAML:

```
trigger: none

jobs:
  - job:  DownloadLeaf
    timeoutInMinutes: 180
    pool:
      vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

    steps:
      
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        inputs:
          source: 'specific'
          project: 'Leaf'
          pipeline: 'Leaf'
          runVersion: 'latest'
          branchName: 'refs/heads/develop'
          allowPartiallySucceededBuilds: true
          patterns: '**.exe'
          downloadPath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
          
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
              script: |
                cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)
                dir
```

Apparently the download works, but the artifact is deleted before finishing the download pipeline artifact task. Is there a way to avoid this? I need to list and install this downloaded artifact.

Raw log:

```
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4539300Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'DownloadPipelineArtifact'
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4541936Z ##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4542546Z ##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4543934Z ##[debug]=> True
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4544517Z ##[debug]Result: True
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4545085Z ##[section]Starting: DownloadPipelineArtifact
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4762712Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4763081Z Task         : Download Pipeline Artifacts
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4763399Z Description  : Download build and pipeline artifacts
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4763642Z Version      : 2.3.1
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4763894Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4764254Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact
2020-10-19T03:59:22.4764685Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-19T03:59:23.7655864Z Download from the specified build: #197
2020-10-19T03:59:23.7680832Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildNumber;issecret=False;]197
2020-10-19T03:59:23.7681693Z Download artifact to: D:\a\1
2020-10-19T03:59:23.9065283Z ##[warning]Please use Download Build Artifact task for downloading Build Artifact type artifact. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops
2020-10-19T03:59:23.9453572Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]Please use Download Build Artifact task for downloading Build Artifact type artifact. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops
2020-10-19T03:59:24.0583745Z Information, Start downloading FCS artifact- TestBuild-Leaf-20201013.3
2020-10-19T03:59:24.0584657Z Information, Minimatch patterns: [**.exe]
2020-10-19T03:59:24.0906614Z Information, Item excluded: TestBuild-Leaf-20201013.3
2020-10-19T03:59:24.0907588Z Information, Item excluded: TestBuild-Leaf-20201013.3/leaf-TestBuild20201013.3-setup.exe
2020-10-19T03:59:24.1072367Z Downloading artifact finished.
2020-10-19T03:59:24.1236846Z ##[section]Finishing: DownloadPipelineArtifact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifact was not deleted in the pipeline. It was just not downloaded. The patterns `**.exe`  you specified in the task is incorrect, which caused no matched files was found and nothing was downloaded.

If you want to download the .exe file in the artifact. You can specify the patterns like this `**/*.exe`.  See [Pattern syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops#match-characters) for more information. See below modified yaml:

```
 - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        inputs:
          source: 'specific'
          project: 'Leaf'
          pipeline: 'Leaf'
          runVersion: 'latest'
          branchName: 'refs/heads/develop'
          allowPartiallySucceededBuilds: true
          patterns: '**/*.exe'
          downloadPath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
```

The artifacts will be downloaded to a subfolder `artifactName` under the path specified in `downloadPath` `ie. $(Pipeline.Workspace)/artifactName`. You can cd to folder `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/artifactName` to list the contents

```
 - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
              script: |
                cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/TestBuild-Leaf-20201013.3
                dir
```

And as it was warning in the task. You can get rid of the warning message by using `Download Build Artifact` task instead of `Download pipeline Artifact`

> ##[warning]Please use Download Build Artifact task for downloading Build Artifact type artifact

Comment: Hi, Levi. First of all, thanks for the explanation and patience. This was my problem, now it's working. About the warning, I'll change the task type. Thank you!